# Cómo enviar un mensaje de whatsapp desde una aplicación de iOS

Tags: ios, whatsapp

Busco crear un botón en iOS (en un iPad) que envié una notificación (mensaje) a un grupo de whatsapp sin intervención humana. Cómo puedo lograr esto?

Comment: Tienes puntos de reputación que indican que conoces cómo funciona el sitio y sabes que el tipo de preguntas en donde no hay código no son bien recibidas. Revisaste la documentación de whatsapp? Hay el link para enviar el mensaje pero *siempre* necesitas intervención humana.

Comment: De igual manera si lograras hacer eso con algún método *"extraño"*, Apple no va a publicar tu app en el AppStore.

Comment: Aqui hay un [articulo](https://pureoxygenlabs.com/how-to-create-a-whatsapp-deep-link-with-a-pre-populated-message/) se llama deep linking o links universales [aqui](https://faq.whatsapp.com/iphone/how-to-link-to-whatsapp-from-a-different-app/?lang=en)

Comment: Gracias @Bicho, el tema es que no hay código porque estoy buscando algún framework que tenga esa característica, por lo cual es valida la consulta. Sobre la publicación en la AppStore, no hay intención de que se publiqué es esta tienda. :)

Comment: @loremipsum gracias, el artículo sólo habla de links normales.